# How to correct my navigation bar and boxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been working on an assignment for one of my classes for a bit and am having trouble. I have included a picture of what I need the webpage to look like. I'll try to add a photo of what my current output is. I can tell you one of the problems is my navigation bar is not all the way to the right like it's supposed to be. Also, my red box is under the white box, rather than beside it.

The HTML I have was something I collaborated on with another developer. He included a line to "insert bootstrap css cdn", but we have not done that in this class yet so I think I need to get it to work without that.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Here are my requirements:

For this assignment, you will be re-creating the web page below in design prototype image.
You must use either of the two design layout techniques in this week’s reading: Flexbox or CSS Grid Layout.
Have the layout centered on the page (margin: 0 auto).
Do not use an image tag (img) to display the image; use the CSS background or background-image property with a container element (e.g. article or div).
Use the box-shadow and text-shadow property to create a shadow effect to the text in the three boxes and the boxes themselves.
[What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv7j6.png)

```css
navbar {

  background-color: #fff8ca;

  padding-bottom: 50px;
  
  margin-left: auto;
  


  /* height: 1vh; */

}

body {

  background-color: #fff8ca;

}

.navbar-brand {

  font-style: italic;

  font-size: 30px;

  color: brown !important;

}

.image h1 {

  z-index: 2;

  position: absolute;

  top: 50%;

  left: 0;

  right: 0;

  font-size: 20px;

  width: 100%;

  height: 26px;

  padding: 0;

  margin: 0;

  margin-top: -13px;

  text-align: center;

  color: white;

  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;

  font-size: 60px;

  font-weight: bold;

  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;

}

.left-block {

  margin: 20px;

  width: 700px;

  height: auto;

  padding: 20px;

  background-color: white;

}

.right-block {

  margin: 20px;

  width: 400px;

  height: auto;

  padding: 20px;

  color: white;

  background-color: red;

}

.shadow {

  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;

  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;

  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;

}

.shadow1 {

  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),

    0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);

}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- insert bootstrap css cdn -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-light justify-content-between">

      <a class="navbar-brand">

        <!-- attach image logo here -->

        Joe's Pizaa Co.</a

      >

      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">

        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#"

          >Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a

        >

        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>

        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">News</a>

        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Menu</a>

        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Locations</a>

      </div>

    </nav>

    <div class="image">

      <h1 class="image-tag">New York's Best Pizaa</h1>

      <img

        class="card-img"

        src="1.jpg"

        style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"

        alt="Card image cap"

      />

    </div>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col col-lg-8">

          <div class="left-block float-left shadow1">

            <p>

              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos,

              nam!

            </p>

            <p>

              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.

              Molestias obcaecati nobis illo reiciendis officiis totam soluta

              et! Deleniti, excepturi amet.

            </p>

          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col col-lg-2">

          <div class="right-block shadow">

            <b>Special Offer:</b>

            <p>

              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam,

              sit.

            </p>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </body>

   <!-- insert bootstrap js cdn -->

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff8ca;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #009900;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 40px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 12px;
  align-items: center;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #009900;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/* use actual image in this class instead of the background color */
.landing-img-container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #009900;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.main-content-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.welcome-text {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.541);
}

.special-offers {
  background-color: #f02525;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.541);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <nav>
        <p class="logo">JOE'S PIZZA CO.</p>
        <ul class="nav-links">
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">News</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Locations</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <section class="landing">
        <!-- replace this div with actual image -->
        <div class="landing-img-container">IMAGE</div>
        <div class="main-content-container">
          <div class="welcome-text">
            <h2>Welcome to Joe's Pizza Co.</h2>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta
              magni eum accusantium quae nobis culpa. Voluptate doloribus
              officia quia vel assumenda laboriosam iure minima quaerat.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="special-offers">
            <h3>Special Offers</h3>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Rerum
              molestiae non sunt blanditiis amet numquam ut at sapiente
              mollitia, eos id, eligendi omnis iure laboriosam?
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Play around with the colors and the images you need. I just restarted from scratch and didn't touch your code. The reason I did that so you can use a site called https://www.diffchecker.com/ to use your original code and compare it to mine and that site will tell you the differences pretty quickly.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will check out that website so I can see what I missed. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: You're very welcome.